# Error when installing ssdeep on windows

Tags: python, windows

I try to install the [ssdeep](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssdeep) python bindings on windows, but it crashes when running build_ext. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
    >c:\Python26\python.exe setup.py install
    running install
    running bdist_egg
    running egg_info
    writing ssdeep.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to ssdeep.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to ssdeep.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'ssdeep.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'ssdeep.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
    running install_lib
    running build_ext
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` is the command to source a file in a POSIX-compatible shell. Either install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to get bash or another POSIX-compatible shell, or manually rewrite `depcomp` (and potentially `configure`) to work with your shell.